# How do you lookup a Windows user's DOMAIN\login based on their email address?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

Most applications on our Windows network identify users by their email address (e.g. Outlook, Lync, Windows Security dialogs, etc.).  However some tools, such as SQL Server Reporting Services, will only accept the DOMAIN\login format when specifying users.

How can I lookup a user's DOMAIN\login name based on their email address?

Comment: Are their email addresses the same as their UPN?

Comment: There are several attributes in the domain that may be the users email address.  For example on my domain the address is stored in userPrincipalName, mail, and proxyAddresses.   But those attributes would only be an email in certain configurations. (ie Exchange sets proxyAddresses)

Comment: @MarkHenderson The email address I'm referring to is what we use to login to Windows.

Comment: @user2196728 Either a script, or some way to look up this info in the Windows UI will work for me.  Honestly, if I can use the user's full name instead of their email address to find their DOMAIN\User name that would be great too.

Comment: The `userPrincipalName` is the attribute that is valid for logging into windows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to present a solution that is specific to the OP's environment, and is therefore unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 3):

Let clear up some misconceptions here.  The username that users in your domain use to authenticate to the examples you mentioned (Outlook, Lync, Windows Security dialogs) **is not** actually an email address.  It may *look like* an email address and in your specific domain it may even be the same value as the user's email address.  But as @Zordache pointed out in his comment, it is actually the [User-Principal-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (UPN).  By default, it tends to be a combination of the user's [SAM-Account-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute and the FQDN of the domain separated by an '@' character: `<sAMAccountName>@<domain FQDN>`.  But technically, it can be anything as long as it's unique in the forest and any other forests that interact with it (thanks for the clarification, HopelessN00b).

The form of username you're looking for is the legacy way to specify an AD username which uses the NetBIOS name of the domain (short name) and the SAM-Account-Name value separated by a '\' character: `<domain short name>\<sAMAccountName>`.

@MTS, @HopelessN00b is correct in his assessment that your answer is not technically right even though it works for your specific environment.  At the very least, the filter argument in your DSQUERY command should use `userPrincipalName` in place of the `mail` attribute.  But allow me to suggest a PowerShell based alternative that uses the built-in ActiveDirectory modules (assuming you have enabled that feature).

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$domain = (get-addomain).NetBIOSName
$samaccountname = (get-aduser -ldapfilter "(userPrincipalName=myuser@contoso.com)").sAMAccountName
$legacyUsername = "$domain\@samaccountname"
```

Comment: `But technically, it can be anything as long as it's unique in the domain (or forest? can't remember at the moment).`  Actually, it needs to be unique in the forest, and if you want to avoid problems, also unique across all forests that interact with each other.  For example, I'm in a position where I have 4 forests in my enterprise - all UPNs need to be unique across all 4 forests if I want user logins to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I was able to come up with on my own, but it seems like there should be a simpler way.

1. Download and install DSQUERY (and related utilities).
   See [Where can I get dsquery and other tools useful for debugging Active Directory issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936829/where-can-i-get-dsquery-and-other-tools-useful-for-debugging-active-directory-is)
2. From the command line:

   > DSQUERY * domainroot -filter
   >   "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=**%1**))" -attr
   >   sAMAccountName

   (Replace **%1** with the email address you're searching with.)

Comment: `but it seems like there should be a simpler way` Yes, a simpler way is just to use AD or Exchange embedded Powershell Cmdlets. By now, the question does not seem very clear.

Comment: This is actually a bad answer, because it makes assumptions that are not universally (or even generally) valid.  I mean, great that it works for you, and your specific environment, but... well, like I said, it's just not a good answer (which may be related to this being a pretty poor question too).

Comment: @user2196728 Either or both of these ideas will likely be helpful for others in the future if you can post them.  For now, the solution I came up with meets my needs (though I am always happy to learn a better way).

Comment: @MTS I don' say it cannot be helpful, i just say that you don't need a third party software for that

Comment: You should really have a look into the Active Directory module for Powershell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx.